# iOS sending a POST and GET in the same request

Tags: ios, json, xcode, post, get

I am successfully posting data as follows:

```
     NSMutableURLRequest *scriptrequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL      URLWithString:@"myurl.com"]];

 [scriptrequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *sendData =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ID=%@&action=List", ID, nil];
NSData *scriptdata = [sendData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[scriptrequest setHTTPBody:scriptdata];

NSError *scripterr;
NSURLResponse *scriptresponse;


NSData *scriptResponseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:scriptrequest returningResponse:&scriptresponse error:&scripterr];
```

My question is, is it possible to also attach GET data to the same call?

Comment: I am afraid you can't do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GET and POST are different types of HTTP Request.

GET Request is majorly used for fetching the web content while POST is for insert/update some content.

So eventually **A single HTTP request can only be of one of the following.**

```
Http types include:

GET
HEAD
POST 
PUT
DELETE
TRACE
OPTIONS
CONNECT
PATCH
```

More technical details at Wikipedia:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol

Comment: Ok, thank you. Would it be possible to form a GET request separate from the POST request and send both requests at the same time?

Comment: I am not sure about your requirements. May be you need to explain more. But still you can use asynchronous requests to geta feel of parallel execution.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are trying to retrieve data from your server, not update. A more typical way to form the request would be to GET http://myurl.com?ID=123&action=List. However, this really depends on how the server code is written.